# Use BQL to get the market caps of unique holdings in multiple ETFs

Tags: excel, bloomberg

To get the market cap in USD of the holdings of an ETF, for example for "IHI US EQUITY" you can use:

`=@BQL("holdings('IHI US EQUITY')","cur_mkt_cap(currency=USD)")`

I am trying to to the same but for the unique value of multiple funds. For example we could add "XHE US EQUITY".

**How can this be done?**

I have tried various notation like [holdings(ETF),holdings(ETF)] but nothing seems to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Union function to combine the two.

```
=@BQL("union(holdings('IHI US EQUITY'),holdings('XHE US Equity'))","cur_mkt_cap(currency=USD)")
```